# Siliverlight: controls visibility changes alignment?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

The following code

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="test.jpg"/>
        <Image Source="test2.jpg"/>
        <TextBlock Text="TeStBlock"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

If I am setting the visibility of the contents of the StackPanel in the codebehind and lets say I set the visibility of the Second image to collapsed. I notice that the `TextBlock` moves to where the Image used to be.

How can I keep the alignment and turn the visibility on or off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Opacity="0"` instead.